# ambiguous use of backgroundColor swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, ambiguous

I just want to simple change background of UIButton after clicking and getting API response.
So I wrote following code.

```
@IBAction func followClick(sender: AnyObject)
{
    //calling SOAP API
    //Getting response
    sender.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 146/255.0, green: 29/255.0, blue: 29/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}
```

But getting error of

> ambiguous use of backgroundColor

Please help me to this simple step.

Answer (score 2):

kinda Dumb...

just replaced with following

```
@IBAction func followClick(sender: UIButton)
```

while connecting IBAction forget to change class fromAnyObject to UIButton.